# jQuery form submit doesn't appear to trigger if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, submit

I have this error but I can't see how to fix it. I've used JSLint with some results (it just tells me `document` isn't a global value, or the 'else clause' was not needed, etc) but no solution.

I have a form to be submitted and I need to compare that both email fields are equal. So I want a nice simple email1 == email2 script, jQuery isn't my strongest point, but I came up with this:

My form ID is "regIn", my email fields are `type="email"` (HTML5) and `id="MailA"` and `id="MailB"` respectively.

I have preloaded jquery 1.11.1.min.js

My jQuery code (see below why the `#forgotten` is still in there):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#forgotten').click(function() {
        $('#passbox').toggle(360);
        return false;
    });

    $('#regIn').submit(function() {
```

// * referenced; but this isn't in the code: `alert('alert1');`

```
        if ($('#MailA').val() === $('#MailB').val()) {
            return true;
        }
        $('#errorMsg').innerHTML("Emails need to be the same!");
        alert('Hello');
        return false;
    });
});
```

So - I use Alerts to see how far the script gets (i know, tacky debugging). firebug doesn't report page errors or script errors that I can see. The "alert 1" always fires on form submission, and successfully shows me the values of `#MailA.val()` and `#MailB.val()`,

But the `if` statement doesn't seem to fire at all. I have tried making the values variables (`var d1 = $('#MailA').val()` etc. ) but that doesn't change anything, the form always submits and neither the `if` or the `else` (which did surround the text below the `if` statement clause but JSLint said it wasn't needed so I removed it).

I have also used variations of syntax, using `!=` and `==` but was also reading from JSLint that `===` and `!==` are preferred.

My HTML:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="regIn" id="regIn" autocomplete="off" accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" method="post">

    <div class="inputContainer">
        <input type="email" value="" tabindex="31" id="MailA" name="regMailA" required>
    </div>

    <div id="errorMsg"></div>

    <div class="inputContainer">
        <input type="email" value="" id="MailB" tabindex="32" name="regMailB" required>
    </div>

    <div class="registerRow">
        <input type="submit" class="regButton" value="Register" tabindex="34">
    </div>
</form>
```

As I said, I've looked around for the last hour or so and I just can't see what it is.

Obviously the code is stripped down for the question, the only other aspect is that there is another piece of jQuery in the `document ready` function - as shown the `#forgotten` appears for showing / hiding an info. box, this works fine.

Comment: Just to notice: it has to be `$('#errorMsg').html("Emails need to be the same!");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please note that you are using:

```
$('#errorMsg').innerHTML("Emails need to be the same!");
```

if you try to alert `$('#errorMsg').innerHTML` it will be undefined.

When you using JQuery selectors `$('#errorMsg')` JQuery will wrap the dom object with JQuery dom object that own JQuery special methods(val, html, etc), so you don't have access to the core method `innerHTML`, instead you should use:

```
$('#errorMsg').html("Emails need to be the same!");
```

Enjoy!